# Show first set of ul li and hide all subsequent using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul class="articles">
    <li>
        <!-- Display these -->
        <ol class="faces">
            <li>
                <a href="#">View More #1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">View More #2</a>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        <!-- Hide these -->
        <ol class="faces">
            <li>
                <a href="#">View More #3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">View More #4</a>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When the page is first loaded, I would like to show the first `ol.faces li's` (with the #1 and #2 anchor links) and hide the subsequent `ol li's`. Is this possible using css without adding any more classes?

Comment: You could use the `:first-child` css-selector, though this is a recent addition and won't work for older browsers.

Comment: `:first-child` is supported all the way back to IE7 ([caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=first-child)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide all `li` tags that are direct descendants of `.article`

```
   .articles>li{
        display:none;
    }
```

Show the first `li` within `.article`

```
.articles>li:first-child{
    display: block;
}
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/xNnpR/

Comment: .articles > li:first-child{
    display: block;
}
Show direct first child or else you will have a numbering issue like your fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can use a selector:

```
li:first-child
{
    /* Your CSS  */
}
```

Declare a DOCTYPE to make it work for IE8 and IE7.

See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_firstchild_more3

Answer (score 0):

```
.articles > li:first-child{
   visibility: visible !important;
}


.articles li{
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: why the downvote? Please explain so that I can learn from your knowledge as obviously if I posted I think this is correct and since you disagree I would like to learn from you and help increasing my knowledge

Comment: `visibility: hidden` is generally a bad way to hide things, as the space where the elements are doesn't go away. It's like setting `opacity: 0;`. Best technique for this instance is `display: none;`